# How much time does it take for Google Webmaster Tools to report 'hreflang' tags?

Tags: google-search-console, hreflang

I have a properly indexed site by Google with a few hundred pages, most of the pages re-crawled on a daily basis (according the crawl stats offered by Google Webmaster Tools). Last week, I have added `hreflang` tags to all pages by link inclusion within `<head/>` section of every page. Yet, within the *International Targeting* tab of the GWT, I still get a message indicating `Your site has no hreflang tags`.

Does anyone know how much time it takes for Google to notice new `hreflang` tags on an old well indexed website?

Comment: Google bots seem to be processing my hreflang tags about once a week. My site has over 150,000 pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The webmaster tool started to show me the `hreflang` tags about 8 days after putting them online. Thus, I guess one should expect those values to be updated - at least from the webmaster console viewpoint - only twice per month or so.